# Scrollable frame in customtkinter with .grid

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I want to create a GUI with two frames, one of which must be scrollable. I tried to create a scrollbar using canvas, but following the instructions from several tutorials I came to something strange:

[image]

I'm using the `.grid` method instead of the simple pack, because I want more control over the placement of elements (many in a row). I tried converting these tutorial methods from `.pack` to `.grid`, maybe that's why it doesn't work.

```py
import customtkinter
import tkinter


class MyGui:
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app
        self.app.geometry("500x300")
        self.app.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.app.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1), weight=1)

        self.frame = customtkinter.CTkFrame(self.app)
        self.frame.grid(
            row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=(20, 5), sticky="NSEW"
        )

        self.canvas = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(self.frame)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky="NSEW")

        self.scrollbar = customtkinter.CTkScrollbar(
            master=self.frame, orientation="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview
        )
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="E")

        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.frame_1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.canvas)
        self.frame_1.grid(
            row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=(20, 5), sticky="NSEW"
        )

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.frame_1, anchor="nw")

        self.frame_2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(master=self.app)
        self.frame_2.grid(
            row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=20, pady=(5, 20), sticky="NSEW"
        )

        for x in range(100):
            customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_1, text=f"Button {x}").grid(
                row=x, column=0
            )
            customtkinter.CTkEntry(
                master=self.frame_1, placeholder_text=f"Entry {x}"
            ).grid(row=x, column=1)
            customtkinter.CTkEntry(
                master=self.frame_1, placeholder_text=f"Entry {x}"
            ).grid(row=x, column=2)

        customtkinter.CTkButton(self.frame_2, text="Lonely button").pack(padx=5, pady=5)


app = customtkinter.CTk()
running = MyGui(app)
app.mainloop()
```

Also note that beside 'crashed' windows, scrollbar does not change position while scrolling because it takes up all his space and frames does not seem to expanding to fill the window.

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm running into similar looking layout issues regarding Frame sizing and scrolling...